# PHP, Jquery, nested html table

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to show additional information in a nested table.
The base html data table is generated through PHP. Some data fields have radio buttons. When a rb has been clicked then the nested data table should be visible below the base data row, but for each row.

PHP code:

```
while (oci_fetch($stmt)){
echo  "<tr>\n"
    . "<td class='v'>" . oci_result($stmt, 'COL1') . "</td>\n"
    . "<td class='v'>" . oci_result($stmt, 'COL2') . "</td>\n"
    . "<td class='v'>" . oci_result($stmt, 'COL3') . "</td>\n"
    . "<td class='v'>" . oci_result($stmt, 'COL4') . "</td>\n"
    . "<td class='v1'><input type='radio' name='info' value='SUB_INFO' id='rbt'>". oci_result($stmt, 'DETAILS') .  "</td>\n"
    . "</tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>\n";
```

Thanks for sharing your ideas!

Comment: you shouldn't be using a static `id` within a loop. Give it a class instead.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet. I have the base table, code snippet above.

Comment: Please be more clear in what you are asking. Maybe create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your PHP script's HTML output.

Comment: I have 2 sql queries. The 1.query shows the base data and the 2.query shows the detailed information. Goal: Show the detailed info in a nested table when a rb in the base table has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your original post with more of the code including the table above it (even if it's just html)? I think I have a solution for you, but I'm fuzzy on exactly what you're trying to do.

Also why not do it like this?

```
<tr> 
<?php $cols = array('COL1','COL2','COL3','COL4'); 
     for ($i=0; $i < count($cols)-1; $i++) { ?>
        <td class='v'> <?php echo oci_result($stmt, $cols[$i] ) ?></td>
<?php } //end the for loop?>
        <td class='v1'>
            <input type='radio' name='info' value='SUB_INFO' id='rbt'><?php echo oci_result($stmt, 'DETAILS') ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will post the html in a while.

Comment: Base table:
COL1   COL2   COL3(radio)   COL4(radio)   <--- Click radio show detail table
                 Detail3       Detail4    <--- Detail table
                 Detail3       Detail4    <--- Detail table

Comment: I'm going to need a lot more raw HTML to help you. Update your OP with the raw html you're trying to make it look like and tell what you're clicking to make something happen. 

I'm thinking more than likely you're going to need AJAX to do what you're wanting